# Performance bottleneck from simple logic?

Tags: java, performance, logic

I'm writing a simulation in Java and I have had a marked decrease in performance today. I used to be able to progress through my timesteps without waiting, but now there are several seconds of lag between timesteps. Through some experimentation I have found a particular line that, when commented out, cause the program to execute smoothly again. It is indicated in my code snippet below:

```
public HashMap<String, Gene> childGenes(String parent, Axes axis, boolean daughter1){
    HashMap<String, Gene> parentGenes = this.cells.get(parent).getGenes();
    HashMap<String, Gene> childGenes = new HashMap<String, Gene>();
    switch(axis){
    case X:
        for(String s: parentGenes.keySet()){
            Gene g = parentGenes.get(s);
            Compartment comp = g.getLocation().getAP();
            /*commenting out this line increases performance*/ if((comp != Compartment.POSTERIOR && daughter1) || (comp != Compartment.ANTERIOR && !daughter1)){
                childGenes.put(g.getName(), new Gene(g.getName(), g.getState(), g.getLocation()).populateCons());
            }
        }
        break;

    //essentially identical cases for Y and Z here
    }
    return childGenes;
}
```

The hashmap has about 30 members, so this for loop will execute 30 times, and this method is called twice in quick succession for about a total of 60 runs. This still seems like small beans in computer terms, and it's not as though the if statement contains anything particularly calculation heavy - right? - but commenting out that single line increases performance like crazy. What could be going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post or link to the Compartment class?

Comment: Also, if you comment out that line and nothing else the program isn't going to compile. Exactly what code do you comment out?

Comment: Compartment is just an enum (with nine possible values, one of which is POSTERIOR).

Comment: I commented out just the if statement and the bracket closing it. Everything still compiles, it's just that more items get added to the childGenes hashmap than intended.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in your analysis. Thus, it's essential to know the compilable snippet that repeats the problem.

Comment: And what's the populateCons() method? My guess from here is that that's your problem, since the if check is trivial and adding *more* items to a hashmap isn't faster than fewer.

Comment: does Compartment entity have any large data associated with it e.g. blob or image which is persisted in database?

Comment: Ok, this is really low-level, but I would try disassembling the two variants to see if the compiler does something funky. (javap -c)